# Strange problem when trying to link C code against ICU Unicode libraries on Linux

Tags: linux, gcc, unicode, linker, icu

I have been playing around with the ICU Unicode libraries and I recently encountered some strange linking errors that have stumped me.

I've narrowed the code down to a minimal example which demonstrates the linker errors :

```
#include <unicode/uchar.h>
#include <unicode/ustdio.h>
#include <unicode/utypes.h>
//#include <unicode/coll.h>

int main(void) {
    UFILE *ustdout;
    ustdout = u_get_stdout();
    UChar32 *ustr1 = L"Ich bin glücklich!";
    u_fprintf(ustdout, "%S\n", ustr1);
    return(0);
}
```

On my Linux Mint 19.2 Cinnamon 64-bit system, compiling the above, according to the icu-config output, gives me :

```
$ gcc c-icu-test-3.c -I/usr/include -licui18n -licuuc -licudata -o c-icu-test-3.bin
/tmp/ccjku7rS.o: In function `main':
c-icu-test-3.c:(.text+0x9): undefined reference to `u_get_stdout_60'
c-icu-test-3.c:(.text+0x34): undefined reference to `u_fprintf_60'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

According to "icu-config --cc --cflags --cppflags --ldflags-libsonly" , I'm using the correct command line options.

I *have* tracked the problem down to something to do with the "U_ICU_ENTRY_POINT_RENAME" macro, and, issuing an "find /usr/include/unicode/ -regextype gnu-awk -regex '(.*.c$)|(.*.h$)' -exec grep -H -n -P '^#define +U_ICU_ENTRY_POINT_RENAME.*$' {} \;" outputs :

```
$ find /usr/include/unicode/ -regextype gnu-awk -regex '(.*\.c$)|(.*\.h$)' -exec grep -H -n -P '^#define +U_ICU_ENTRY_POINT_RENAME.*$' {} \;
/usr/include/unicode/uvernum.h:109:#define U_ICU_ENTRY_POINT_RENAME(x)    U_DEF2_ICU_ENTRY_POINT_RENAME(x,U_ICU_VERSION_SUFFIX,U_LIB_SUFFIX_C_NAME)
/usr/include/unicode/uvernum.h:113:#define U_ICU_ENTRY_POINT_RENAME(x)    U_DEF2_ICU_ENTRY_POINT_RENAME(x,U_ICU_VERSION_SUFFIX)
```

I have made sure that I have all the necessary header files and libraries. There, though, appears to be some type of version mismatch, but I don't know how to solve it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

jdb2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need also flag `--ldflags-icuio` for icu-config.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! :D It solved my problem! :) Seems that I forgot to include the ICU I/O library :) And I was blaming the library :P ( It's almost *never* the compiler's fault :) )